# Eloquent Missing Equal sign when setting 2 BLOBs to null

Tags: php, eloquent, lumen

In my Lumen application I want to update two Blobs of a single data set to NULL.
When I try it, I get following error:

> ORA-00927: missing equal sign

This is my code:

```
$data->name = "Test";
$data->blob1 = null;
$data->blob2 = null;
$data->save();
```

When I update a single blob (By commenting the other one out), the code works in both cases. It just breaks when trying to update both blobs at the same time.

EDIT:

The code works, if only one the two columns has a valid BLOB in its Database entry before updating with NULL.
If both columns contain a BLOB before updating the entry, it fails.

Calling save() twice, fixes the problem, but it seems like a workarround rather than a fix.

Comment: do you have some triggers on update?

Comment: Nope, I dont think so

Comment: try to comment one of the blob (as you already did, but try to comment the other one)

Comment: I tried commenting out both updates, with a single update it always works.